# Java: How to stop user from entering a file using JFileChooser

Tags: java

Hi Stackoverflow community, I have a java question.

I am making a program that uses JFileChooser, the JFileChooser is set for Directories only and I have a Jtextfield that sets the text to the Dir of the folder chosen however I must error correct for the user specifying a specific file in this text field. I have set the .setEditable(false) for this text field so the user cannot type in the text field, the user must use the button associated with the JFileChooser to set the Dir. However the user can still input text into the JFileChooser GUI that pops up when looking for a file, and the entered text will be placed into the associated JTextField when the open button is hit. Does anyone know a way to disable the editabilty of the text field on the JFileChooser pop up? Maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way, But basically the user must only be able to select a Dir and not be able to specify a file in anyway.

Comment: Looks like you could use JFileChooser#setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY) at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode-int-.  Even with that you should check that getSelectedFile returns a directory and reject or accept.

Comment: Precisely, this is what I have done, however the user can still complete the path to a file and press Open and it will place the full file path in the text field, having a file specified will cause the program to break, I must only allow for a folder path in the JFileChooser folder selection GUI. Any ideas how to disable the editability for JFileChooser GUI pop up?

Comment: Thank you for pasting the link to oracle website, I was able to find where I was messing up. The JFileChooser was set to accept files, I had to change the JFileChooser to use the .getCurrentDirectory().getpath() doing this overwrites the user entering a file in the JFileChooser GUI, if the user specifies a file, and clicks okay, the parent directory of the file will instead be placed in the JTextField. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
public void setFileSelectionMode(int mode)
```

Sets the JFileChooser to allow the user to just select files, just select 
directories, or select both files and directories. The default is 
JFilesChooser.FILES_ONLY.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you may have misread what I was asking though, I have directories only set up already, however the user can still complete the path to a file with the JFileChooser pop up GUI, doing this will cause an error with the program, I must allow the user to only select a folder and not be able to enter the file path through the JFileChooser folder selector GUI.